# Why use jpa findall will cause transaction commit first

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, transactions

```
@Transactional
public boolean updateAdminUser(Long userId, CreateUpdateAdminUserDto createUpdateAdminUserDto) {

//other code

adminUserRoleRepository.deleteAdminUsersRolesByAdminUserId(userId);
adminUserRoleRepository.findAll();
dminUserRepository.save(adminUser);

}
```

When I want to add data after deletion, because there is no commit at the time of deletion, it will cause duplication of data, but when I add **adminUserRoleRepository.findAll()**
the deletion  will be committed first, and my data will be successfully added to the database. I would like to ask why the findAll() of jpa will cause the transaction to be committed first.

Comment: It doesn't commit it only flushes the pending changes to the database when doing a select.

Comment: Indeed, the select will trigger the flush of pending update queries, but `save` isn't supposed to do it as well ?

Comment: Why would save (merge/persist) do it? Flush is expensive and unnecessary most of the time. It is only required to be called immediately before the transaction commits, in a before completion event. It is also done automatically when queries that hit the database might need to see changes within the persistence context. Otherwise, JPA providers (mostly, as the spec doesn't require it) batch up changes as much as possible instead of flushing on each call. If a delete must be performed before other save operations occur, you need to force a flush to control the order of statements.

Comment: Thanks for everyone's replies, it seems that if I want to use delete and save at the same time, I have to use flush after delete

Answer (score 0):

To add to what @Chris has already said, the order in which the operations are carried out is as follows (see [performExecutions(EventSource session)](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/event/internal/AbstractFlushingEventListener.html#performExecutions(org.hibernate.event.spi.EventSource))):

> 1. Inserts, in the order they were performed
> 2. Updates
> 3. Deletion of collection elements
> 4. Insertion of collection elements
> 5. Deletes, in the order they were performed

If you want the data operation to be reflected immediately so that you can take into account the change. You must perform a flush and, as it is in a transaction, it can always be rolled back before it's committed.